# How to copy deps from GOPATH using go mod vendor?

Tags: go, govendor, go-modules

How do I make `go mod vendor` copy dependencies from `GOPATH` instead of downloading them over the network?

Comment: Shouldn't it always look for dependencies in GOPATH first and only if it doesn't find them there, look for them over the network?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this in general: modules are intentionally a separate workspace from `GOPATH`, and `go mod vendor` copies dependencies from the module workspace.

That said, if you can figure out what versions the various repos in your `GOPATH` are sync'd to, you can run `go get -d <repo>@<version>` within your module for each such repo to synchronize your module workspace to that version.